# Could an electrically pumped rocket stage position its batteries to enable it to re-enter stably nose-first?

Tags: reentry, electron, rutherford-engine

Are the batteries in existing or planned electrically pumped rocket stages massive enough to change the centre of mass of the empty stage such that new re-entry strategies are available?

e.g.

Could the batteries be placed at the top of the stage so that it could re-enter nose first stably?

or

Allow a sideways skydiver re-entry with air-brakes of similar relative size fore and aft to the ones on SpaceX's StarShip?

Comment: FWIW, at least my experience playing KSP is that nose-first re-entry is almost *never* a good idea. Depending on the design of your vessel, you generally want to re-enter either sideways (for maximum drag on a long vessel) or backwards (i.e. engines pointing forwards, ready for deceleration). Nose first has neither of those advantages.

Comment: No. If the batteries were that heavy they'd use turbopumps.